# Apply Form to show and hide elements depending on if submitted or not

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Apologies for the long title.

I need a form to show and hide elements depending on different outcomes.

So, First of all I want the form to disappear while the form is being checked over and replaced with a gif loading icon (Currently working)

If the form sends i want it to display a hidden div element and finally if the form doesnt send I want it to display another div element which is the error message

```
   function applySubmit() {
    $("#ApplicationForm").hide();
    $("#ProgressBar").show();
    $("#applyForm").ajaxSubmit( {
    url: $("#applyForm").attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
    $("#messageBox").html(data);
    $("#ProgressBar").hide();
    $("#success").show();
    }
    });
    return false;
    }
```

At the moment it all works as it should, however it clones the whole page under the footer and shows only the `progressbar`

If i can provide any more information to help me with this please let me know! 
Thanks for all and any help!

I made a fiddle but doenst seem to work on there

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eeazvdgj/2/)

Comment: For starters, your div ID's are case sensitive, first change all your id's to match the jquery

Comment: Have you updated the question with corrected code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is that portion of your code working

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/eeazvdgj/3/

```
    function applySubmit() {
        $("#ApplicationForm").hide();
        $("#progressbar").show();

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Knew i forgot something :l

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  $('form').on('submit',function(){
   if ($('form').valid()){
    $("#success").show();
   }
   else{
    $('#errors').show();
   }
  });
```